# Why is my edited answer greyed out?

Tags: support

I undeleted my first posted answer and revised it to take into account the comments.

Now, the answer is just greyed out; someone else's answer to the same question is displayed normally, so there appears something wrong with the editing I did.

Could someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers with a net score below a certain threshold are grayed out to de-emphasize incorrect or otherwise bad answers. Your post is currently at a score of -4. Your edit did bump the question to the front page, so now people will see it again and may cast new or changed votes on your answer.